# Metric Space Open Sets.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a metric. I've shown $\sigma(s,t) = \frac{\rho(s,t)}{1 + \rho(s,t)}$ is also a metric on $X$.

I'm having trouble showing that the open sets defined by the metric $\rho$ are the same as the open sets defined by $\sigma$. I know I must show that an open ball in the $\rho$ metric is an open set in the $\sigma$ metric, and that an open ball in the $\sigma$ metric is an open set in the $\rho$ metric. Any hints or advice?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: note that $\sigma=\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}=1-\frac{1}{1+\rho}$ is strictly increasing on $[0;+\infty)$, therefore, $\sigma<\epsilon$ implies $\rho<\delta$ (for some $\delta$) and vice versa.

Comment: Just be careful considering two cases: $\epsilon\ge 1$ and $0<\epsilon<1$ when you go one direction.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't entirely understand yet. Could you explicitly show one way?

Comment: $\sigma(\rho)$ is a strictly increasing function, hence, bijective and has inverse on the range. A $\sigma$-ball at $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ is the set of points $y$ such that $\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$, which corresponds to points $y$ such that $\rho(x,y)<\delta$ for some $\delta$, i.e. a $\rho$-ball. Once again, just be careful enough with large values for $\epsilon$ (for example, $\epsilon\ge 1$ if $\rho$ goes to infinity).

Comment: If this does not help, draw a graph of the function $\sigma(\rho)$ and try to understand why $\sigma<\epsilon$ implies $\rho<\delta$ for some delta, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The other direction is immediate, because for all $x,y\in X$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sigma(x,y)=\frac{\rho(x,y)}{1+\rho(x,y)}\leq \frac{\rho(x,y)}{1+0}=\rho(x,y).
\end{align*}
On the other hand $\sigma<1$ since:
\begin{align*}
\sigma(x,y)=\frac{\rho(x,y)}{1+\rho(x,y)}< \frac{1+\rho(x,y)}{1+\rho(x,y)}=1.
\end{align*}
So by rearranging the terms in the definition of $\sigma$ we get (which is well defined by the previous remark):
\begin{align*}
\rho(x,y)=\frac{\sigma(x,y)}{1-\sigma(x,y)}
\end{align*}
Thus for any $0<\varepsilon<1$ by choosing $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}$ we see that $\sigma(x,y)<\varepsilon$ implies $\rho(x,y)<\delta$.